# Dynamic data visualization in angular2 using HTML/angular2 template engine

Tags: angular, dynamic, data-visualization, markup, angular2-template

When working with data in the frontend there are often challenges to visualize data understandable for the user. The (dynamic) data to visualize is well structured and simple (with a focus on data size and the prevention of overloading).

But the data structure below (`DATA`) is off course not the best visual representation for the user.

Let me explain the problem I can't solve well yet using the following example:

*And let me point out here that I come from a perspective of template engines like `EJS` etc. which might be the main reason why I don't find a simple way to solve — don't know...*

**Example: Matrix Table (e.g. time slots in a year by a weekly resolution)**

**Data (`DATA`):**

```
[
    {
        name:'Slot 1',
        slot:{
                start:3,
                end:5
             }
    },
    {
        name:'Slot 2',
        slot:{
                start:32,
                end:50
             }
    },
    {
        name:'Slot 3',
        slot:{
                start:10,
                end:26
             }
    }
]
```

**Visualization:**

The data should be rendered into a matrix `table` with three `rows` (as many rows as items in the data) 
and with a resolution of 52 weeks (`cells`) per `row`. And the range (`start` - `end`) should be highlighted in that table.

[image]

As mentioned above I came with a perspective of other templating engines and so I try to figure out how to write `loops` or so in angular to get this visualization. In other templating engines I would 'interpret' the data within the template and create the `HTML` in two `loops` because this "overloading" is only relevant for visual purposes.

**Dynamically generated markup (`EJS`) - way**

```
<table>

<%  var i, weeks=52;
    for(i=0;i<DATA.length;i+=1){
%>

<tr>
    <td><%-DATA[i].name%></td>

    <%  var j;
        for(j=1;j<=weeks;j+=1){
    %>

    <td class="<%((j>=DATA[i].slot.start && j<= DATA[i].slot.end)?'in-range':'')%>">
        <%- j %>
    <td>


    <%}%>

</tr>

<%}>

</table>
```

**Qustion:**

Actually I'm not able to solve this in an efficient way in `Angular 2.x` and the only solution I can achieve yet (which is not good of course) is to write the entire `HTML` for such a `table` matrix.

This obiously ends in a huge overhead whenever there is a change in the `HTML` required (e.g. adding a `class` or so). I know search & replace in the markup ;) but it's still a lot of markup to maintain which could be generated and I think there must be a way to do that in Angular2 either.

Thanks for any help pointing me into a better direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get desired layout with this code:

```html
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of DATA">
      <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let week of weeks"
          [class.in-range]="row.slot.start <= week && week <= row.slot.end">
        {{ week }} 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

where `weeks = [1, 2, 3, ..., 52]` or, with this helper function:

```ts
export function range(count: number, from = 0) {
  return Array.from(Array(count)).map((_, i) => i + from);
}
```

```html
<td *ngFor="let week of range(52)">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I previously had the idea using that "dummy" array too but thought it can't be the way to go. Now where I'm seeing that helper function I think that's a way which is achievable (even if the matrix get's more complex. Let me ask where to put helper functions in a `angular-cli` app?

Comment: I keep them in shared folder (`src/app/shared/shared.utils.ts`)